# Deducing a function pointer return type

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

I think code will better illustrate my need:

```
template <typename F>
struct return_type
{
  typedef ??? type;
};
```

so that:

```
return_type<int(*)()>::type -> int
return_type<void(*)(int,int)>::type -> void
```

I know of `decltype` and `result_of` but they need to have arguments passed. I want to deduce the return type of a function pointer from a single template parameter. I cannot add the return type as a parameter, because that's exactly what I want to hide here...

I know there's a solution in boost, but I can't use it, and an attempt to dig it out from boost resulted in a spectacular failure (as it often does).

C++11 solutions welcome (as long as supported in VS2012).

Comment: When writing function binders, one needs to treat the "void" return type differently, so I have a template that is specialized on `void`. To use it I need the return type, and I don't want to retype all the parameter counts again.

Answer (score 14):

If you can use variadic templates (November '12 CTP), this should work:

```
template <class F>
struct return_type;

template <class R, class... A>
struct return_type<R (*)(A...)>
{
  typedef R type;
};
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/iZr2KH).

If you can't use variadic templates, you'll have to provide specific specialisations for 0, 1, 2, ... parameters (by hand or preprocessor-generated).

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, if you want to work with variadic functions as well, you'll have to add one extra partial specialisation (or one for each parameter count in the no-variadic-templates case):

```
template <class R, class... A>
struct return_type<R (*)(A..., ...)>
{
  typedef R type;
};
```

Comment: I can't use CTP, and I hoped I could avoid somehow the pain of writing all of those types myself. I can't believe there is no standard solution...

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz: If you look at [function_traits.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/type_traits/function_traits.hpp) in boost, it does exactly what is in the answer, but writes it all out. You could just copy and paste from there.

Comment: Formally, given N function types for which that template works, this misses `(3 * N) * (2 * N) * N` other function types for which your template does not work. As an example, given `void()`, your template does not work for `void()const`, `void() volatile`, `void() const volatile`, `void(...)`, `void(...)const`, ..., `void() &`, `void()&&`, ..., `void(...)const volatile&&` and so on.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb How do you create a pointer to function (*not* pointer to member function) which can point to a `const`-qualified or ref-qualified function?

Comment: @Angew OK that's a good point :) So you will only miss `N` function types :)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I've added a case for the variadic functions. Were those the `N` ones left? It's nice syntax with the ellipses there, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since the question has been asked. For C++17, there is an interesting option (using keyword auto). However, the syntax is a bit different from what was originally asked, but the result (a type) is the same.

First, we need a helper function. As you see here, the function accepts a function pointer and returns an object of type R. We need this only for a decltype statement and therefore this function will never be called, so a forward declaration is sufficient.

```
template<typename R, typename... ARGS>
static R return_type(R (*)(ARGS...));  // forward declaration only for decltype
```

The trick is to provide the function pointer as a template auto parameter, which is forwarded to a decltype statement:

```
template<auto FUNCTION_POINTER>
using ReturnType = decltype(return_type(FUNCTION_POINTER));
```

Now it is easy to get the return type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename R, typename... ARGS>
static R return_type(R (*)(ARGS...));  // forward declaration only for decltype

template<typename R, typename... ARGS>
static R return_type(R (*)(ARGS..., ...));  // overloaded variant for functions with C-ellipsis

template<auto FUNCTION_POINTER>
using ReturnType = decltype(return_type(FUNCTION_POINTER));

int func1(char c, int i, long l);  // also here only forward declarations needed
void func2(unsigned u, float f);
double func3(bool b);
bool func4(int, ...);

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<int, ReturnType<func1>> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<void, ReturnType<func2>> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<double, ReturnType<func3>> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<void, ReturnType<func1>> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<void, ReturnType<func4>> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<bool, ReturnType<func4>> << std::endl;
}
```

You can try the complete example in Wandbox:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/sKemxB44dgAVDlP6

Update in example: overloaded helper for C-ellipsis functions. I use this for several glibc library functions.