# Can someone explain how to use result_of within template?

Tags: c++, templates, result-of

I'm trying to create a delayable call object.  Something along the lines of (pseudo-code):

```
template <class FN>
struct delayable_call
{
    return-type-of-FN call(); // <-- I'd like to use result_of here.

    template<class ArgTypes...>
    delayable_call(FN* pFn, ArgTypes... args);

    FN* fn;
    args-saving-struct;
};
```

I tried using result_of::type for the return type of call, but get errors during instantiation of the template because apparently the argument types need to be specified separately.

Instantiation:

```
int foo(bool, double); // function prototype.

delayable_call<int(bool, double)> delayable_foo(foo, false, 3.14); // instantiation
```

The error messages and documentation I've read about result_of seem to indicate that the argument types must also be specified.  So instead of `result_of<FN>::type`, I'd need to specify `result_of<FN(bool, double)>::type`.  This does actually fix the compilation problem I'm having, but breaks the generality of the template.

So, how can I use result_of with a template parameter when the template parameter represents the function signature?

Comment: I'm probably utterly missing your question, but I *think* `std::result_of<decltype(FN)>` is what you're looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deducing a function pointer return type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695564/deducing-a-function-pointer-return-type)

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to reimplement `std::bind`.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but what does it mean to have a "result_of" for a class?  In the code above, FN is a class, and classes don't have return types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <class FN> struct delayable_call;
template<class R, class...Args> delayable_call<R(Args...)>{
  typedef R(*)(Args...) pFN;
```

replace your `delayable_call` with a specialization, and you will extrace both `R` and `Args...`.  You need `Args...` anyhow to store the parameters.

However, a library-strength delayable call will end up using type erasure.  The easiest way is a simple `std::function<R()>` where you shove a lambda into it:

```
int foo(double);
double x = 7;
std::function<int()> delayed_foo = [x]{ return foo(x); }
```

and capture by value unless you really, really mean it to capture by reference.

You could deduce `R` via:

```
template<typename Fn, typename... Args>
std::function< typename std::result_of<Fn(Args...)>::type()>
make_delayed_call( Fn&& fn, Args&&... args ) {
  return [=]{ return fn(std::move(args)...); }
}
```

which should deduce your `R` from the callable object and the arguments.  This captures everything by copy -- capture by move requires either more boilerplate, or C++14.

Comment: That's mean, though: What if you want to delay calling a lambda or a `std::function`?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943525/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-the-parameter-type-and-return-type-of-a-lambda

Comment: @KerrekSB that is a different problem -- the OP asked for `delayable_call<Signature>` to correspond to a delayable call on a function pointer.  The general version ends up using type erasure on an object that wraps both the args and the callable, and `delayable_call` is templated *only* on the `R` value.  The `R` value can be deduced by a `make_delayable_call` function.  If the OP wants that more complex one, I can write it.